# For what options does the "delta hedging rule" apply?

Tags: options, delta-hedging, replication, hedge, delta-neutral

I'm reading Shreve's *Stochastic Calculus for Finance, Volume II*. In chapter 4, he derives the "delta hedging rule":

$$\Delta(t) = c_x(t, S(t)) \text{ for all } t \in [0, T)\text{.}\tag{1}$$

This says that a self-financing portfolio $X(t)$ that needs to replicate an option with random price $c(t, S(t))$ at time $t$,

$$X(t) = c(t, S(t))\text{,}\tag{2}$$

needs to long $c_x(t, S(t))$ of the underlying asset, assuming that the value of the asset follows a log-normal distribution.

This appears (to me) to be a very general solution to the hedging problem that applies to many classes of exotic options.

However, in chapter 5, Shreve requires the Martingale representation theorem to compute $\Delta(t)$. On page 223, we are given

$$\Delta(t)=\frac{\tilde{\Gamma}}{\sigma(t)D(t)S(t)},\ \ 0 \leq t \leq T\text{.}\tag{3}$$

About this formula, he says

> The Martingale Representation Theorem argument of this section
> justifies the risk-neutral pricing formula (5.2.30) and (5.2.31), but
> it does not provide a practical method of finding the hedging
> portfolio $\Delta(t)$. The final formula [(3)] for $\Delta(t)$
> involves the integrand $\tilde{\Gamma}(t)$ in the martingale
> representation (5.3.4) of the discounted derivative security price.
> While the Martingale Representation Theorem guarantees that such a
> process $\tilde{\Gamma}$ exists and hence a hedge $\Delta(t)$ exists,
> it does not provide a method for finding $\tilde{\Gamma}(t)$. We
> return to this point in Chapter 6.

I found this paragraph confusing because it does not seem to acknowledge that the author has already found such a $\Delta(t)$ in (1). I tried to read ahead to chapter 6, but I have found myself unable to find the answer to this question:

**For what kinds of options should a replicating portfolio long/short $\Delta(t)$ of the underlying according to $(1)$? For what kinds of options is this hedge in any way "incorrect"?**

Some examples: (1) obviously applies to European options with fixed volatility and rate of return. What if your model assumes variable volatility? What about American options?

Comment: The martingale representation theorem can be used to more formally show that a hedging strategy replicates the option payoff. If there are many sources of uncertainty the issue with a delta hedging strategy is that you are not hedged against all sources of risk, e.g. volatility of stock changing.

Comment: Another issue may be if the underlying can experience *jumps* (e.g.. S(t) is a Jump Diffusion process) in that case also Delta hedging cannot remove all risk. The proof of delta hedging requires continuous paths for S(t).

Comment: @AlRacoon the delta does not change sign, but it sounds like binary/digital options may be a contradiction to the generality of (1). I don't see why that would be because binary options should satisfy the derivation of (1) (since they also adhere to the Black-Scholes PDE).

Comment: @user54908 I stand corrected.  The change in delta changes sign at the barrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 5.5.2 (Hedging with One Stock) paragraph that includes (3) does *not* assume that the value of the payoff at *any* $t$ is Markovian, that is, it is a function of $S(t)$ *only*, so there is no "delta" as in (1) to use.

Summary 6.7 has the answer to what Shreve does want to say about formula (3) (in particular the three paragraphs I highlighted; note that Shreve defines and works with a Markov diffusion SDE as underlying).

> 6.7 Summary
>
> **When the underlying price of an asset is given by a
> stochastic differential equation, the asset price is Markov and the
> price of any non-path-dependent derivative security based on that
> asset is given by a partial differential equation.** In order to price
> path-dependent securities, one first seeks to determine
> the variables on which the path-dependent payoff depends and then
> intro­ duce one or more additional stochastic differential equations
> in order to have a system of such equations that describes the
> relevant variables. If this can be done, then again the price of the
> derivative security is given by a partial differential equation. This
> leads to the following four-step procedure for finding the pricing
> differential equation and for constructing a hedge for a derivative
> security.
>
> 1. Determine the variables on which the derivative security
>    price depends. In addition to time t, these are the underlying asset
>    price S(t) and possibly other stochastic processes. We call these
>    stochastic processes the state processes. One must be able to
>    represent the derivative security payoff in terms of these state
>    processes.
> 2. Write down a system of stochastic differential equations for the state pro­ cesses. Be sure that, except for the driving Brownian
>    motions, the only random processes appearing on the right-hand sides
>    of these equations are the state processes themselves. This ensures
>    that the vector of state processes is Markov.
> 3. **The Markov property guarantees that the derivative security price at each time is a function of time and the state processes at that
>    time. The discounted option price is a martingale under the
>    risk-neutral measure. Compute the differential of the discounted
>    option price, set the dt term equal to zero, and obtain thereby a
>    partial differential equation.**
> 4. **The terms multiplying the Brownian motion differentials in the discounted derivative security price differential must be matched by
>    the terms multiplying the Brownian motion differentials in the
>    evolution of the hedging portfolio value; see (5.4.27). Matching
>    these terms determines the hedge for a short position in the
>    derivative security.**